# asp.net + Custom validator not validating

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to use a customvalidator to validate a DIV form and then close it if there is no validation errors. Below is my code, I can't get my custom validator to work, when I click submit, nothing validates, not sure what's wrong. Please advice. Thanks.

```
function validateRedemptionDialog(src, args) {

                var rDate = document.getElementById('<%=uitxtRedemptionDate.ClientID%>').value;


                if (rDate == "") {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                    return;
                }
                args.IsValid = true;
            }


function closeRedemptionDialog() {
            $('#dialog_Active_Redemption_confirm').dialog('close');
        }   

<div id="dialog_Active_Redemption_confirm" style="display: none">
                <div class="section_body">
                    <div class="section_body_content">

                        <div class="row">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uilblRedemptionDate" Text="<%$ Resources:MembersNContactsManagerResources, uigrdhdrTransDate %>"
                                CssClass="label">
                            </asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uitxtRedemptionDate" runat="server" CssClass="text DatePicker" Style="width: 120px;
                                margin-right: 2px;">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="ctvtxtCamDateEnd" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateRedemptionDialog"
                        ControlToValidate="uitxtRedemptionDate" ErrorMessage='<img src="../Images/icons/error.png" style="vertical-align:middle"/> XXX!'
                        Font-Names="arial" Font-Size="X-Small" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uilblRedemptionAmountSpent" Text="<%$ Resources:MembersNContactsManagerResources, uilblRedemptionAmountSpent %>"
                                CssClass="label">
                            </asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uitxtRedemptionAmountSpent" runat="server" Style="width: 120px;">
                            </asp:TextBox>         

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <ul class="inline" style="margin-left: 137px; padding: 3px;">
                                <li><span class="button grey_btn">
                                    <%--Submit button--%>
                                    <asp:Button ID="uibtnRedemption" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources : MembersNContactsManagerResources, uilblSubmit %>" OnClientClick="javascript:closeRedemptionDialog();"/>
                                    <span>&nbsp;</span> </span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validator will not validate empty text with your current configuration.
Set [ValidateEmptyText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx) to `true` if you need it to fire even when the user has entered nothing.

A CustomValidator does not need to have a [ControlToValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx). If you need to validate in any case, you should leave that property empty.